# How can I create empty JSON keys (nested or not) using a string?

Tags: javascript, json

I currently have this code built in JS, but it's really, really ugly.

Is there any better way to approach it?

The way it works basically is pushing a string like app.chat.test to be the key, and value like teststr.

I test the lengths to see if the "parent" key is there, otherwise we build it.

```
function constructJson(jsonKey, jsonValue){
    //REWRITE!!!!!!!!
   let jsonObj = langFile;
   let jsonKeyArr = jsonKey.split('.')
   if (jsonKeyArr.length === 1) {
       if (valToAdd === undefined) {
           if (jsonObj[jsonKey] === undefined) {
               jsonObj[jsonKey] = {}
           }
       } else {
           if (jsonObj[jsonKey] === undefined) {
               jsonObj[jsonKey] = valToAdd
           }
       }
   } else if (jsonKeyArr.length === 2) {
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] = jsonValue
       }
   } else if (jsonKeyArr.length === 3) {
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]] = jsonValue
       }
   } else if (jsonKeyArr.length === 4) {
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]][jsonKeyArr[3]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]][jsonKeyArr[3]] = jsonValue
       }
   } else if (jsonKeyArr.length === 5) {
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]][jsonKeyArr[3]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]][jsonKeyArr[3]] = {}
       }
       if (jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]][jsonKeyArr[3]][jsonKeyArr[4]] === undefined) {
           jsonObj[jsonKeyArr[0]][jsonKeyArr[1]][jsonKeyArr[2]][jsonKeyArr[3]][jsonKeyArr[4]] = jsonValue
       }
   } else if (jsonKeyArr.length > 5) {
      return console.log("Length over 5 not supported yet!")
   }

   return jsonObj;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do exactly? By the way `undefined` is not a protected keyword in javascript so your test to check if the attribute is defined or not is not safe.

Comment: Hi, @C.Champagne

If that's the case, sorry to use the undefined keyword in the first place.


This code is supposed to add a key/value into a JSON file, but creates the "parent" keys if they don't exist. Example key is: "app.chat.test", if app exists, it continues, but if chat does not continue and is not the last value, it builds a chat {} and then test and value.


Sorry if I'm not making myself very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OF course it's possible, a simple loop will perfeclty do the job.

```js
function constructJson(jsonKey, jsonValue){
    //REWRITE!!!!!!!!
   langFile = {a:{}, foo:{}};// remove this for your own code
   var jsonObj = langFile;
   var jsonKeyArr = jsonKey.split('.');
   var currentValue = jsonObj;
   for(var i = 0; i < jsonKeyArr.length;i++){
       if(currentValue[jsonKeyArr[i]]===undefined){
          currentValue[jsonKeyArr[i]] = {};
       }
       if(i < jsonKeyArr.length-1){
       currentValue =  currentValue[jsonKeyArr[i]];
       }else{
            currentValue[jsonKeyArr[i]] = jsonValue;
       }
   }
   return jsonObj;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(constructJson("a.b.cd.ef", "toto")));
```

I just assigning to a temporary variable each sublevel. When i'm on the last i'm assigning the value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, using the javascript reduce function on the array created from the splitted string.

```
function namespaceCreateExceptLast(representationOfElementToCreate, baseNamespace) {
    var tokens;
    if (typeof representationOfElementToCreate !== 'string')
        throw new Error('Expecting string as first parameter');
    if (baseNamespace === undefined)
        baseNamespace = window;

    tokens = representationOfElementToCreate.split('.');

    // Remove the last element (which will contain the value)
    tokens.pop();

    // Use reduce to create part by part your new object
    return tokens.reduce(function (prev, property) {
        if (typeof prev !== 'object') {
            throw Error('One property is already defined but not an object, namespace creation has failed', property);
            return undefined;
        } else {
            if (!prev[property])
                prev[property] = {};
            return prev[property];
        }
    }, baseNamespace);
};
```

Then you can have:

```
function constructJson(jsonKey, jsonValue){
    let jsonObj = langFile;
    var lastItem = namespaceCreateExceptLast(jsonKey, jsonObj);
    var lastKey = jsonKey.substring(jsonKey.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    lastItem[lastKey] = jsonValue;
}
```

I have added some comments and exceptions to help you understand how it's done, but it's mainly based on the reduce function which you can easily get help for (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce).